# JSON.stringify result is random

Tags: javascript, json

JSON.stringify does not maintain the order of the keys. So it seems like random result everytime.

```
var obj = { name: 'kumar', age: 28, location: 'delhi'}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

It returns following in different time

```
 "{"name":"kumar","age":28,"location":"delhi"}"
 "{"age":28,"name":"kumar","location":"delhi"}"
```

How to return the same result everytime? is there any option to sort keys in the JSON string?

Comment: As you will be referring to valuess by key, there is no need to maintain the order

Comment: [Fiddle returns the same order always](http://jsfiddle.net/827WX/)

Comment: when i get the object from server and try to stringify it, then it does not return in order.